# How do I extract a tarball, skipping some of the leading directories?

Tags: server, backup, archive, tar

I am archiving a folder using following command:

```
tar jcf "home/username/forum/forum.tar.bz2" /var/www/forum/
```

Then I am extracting using :

```
tar jxf forum.tar.bz2 ./
```

It extracts correctly, but creates `/home/username/forum/var/www/forum` folder. What do I need to do in order to extract it into `/home/username/forum` folder?

Thank you

Comment: My money is on that you can't do this with just tar. I'd say if you have to do this often use the -C argument and a short bash script.

Comment: @sebastian_k. I think you have lost your money:). dv3500ea solved it with just tar command and this is what I was looking for.

Comment: ... so the -C *did* work. I stand corrected, money lost. :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When creating the archive use `-C /var/www/` to change the current directory to /var/www while creating the archive.

```
tar jcf home/username/forum/forum.tar.bz2 -C /var/www/ forum
```

This will cause the 'forum' folder to be in the top level of the archive and will therefore extract directly into the current folder when you run:

```
tar jxf forum.tar.bz2 ./
```

Answer (score 12):

In addition to [dv3500ea's answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59762/one-question-about-tar-command/59766#59766), you can use the next command to extract tarballs containing `var/www/forum/` to `forum/`:

```
tar xjf forum.tar.bz2 --strip-components=2
```

`var/` and `www/` are two path components, hence the `2` in `--strip-components`.

If you're not sure what's inside a tarball, use the `t` option:

```
tar tjf forum.tar.bz2
```

Pipe it through `less` so you an use arrow keys for scrolling.

A general note about the options used:

- `x` - extracts a tarball, I always place it as first option since it's most logical to see what a command does
- `c` - creates a tarball
- `t` - lists the contents of a tarball
- `j` - make tar uncompress bzip2 compressed tarballs. This is redundant with the `.bz2` extension, so you may remove this option as well
- `f` - this option expects a filename as argument, it's either the tarball to be extracted (`tar xf file.tar.bz2`) or created (`tar cf file.tar.bz2`)

Answer (score 0):

The fast (and possibly wrong) solution would be to change your command to change directories before tarring. IE:

```
cd /var/www/forum; tar jcf "home/username/forum/forum.tar.bz2" .
```