# tar: "Cann't stat: No such file or directory"

Tags: backup, tar

Following command `sudo tar jcf /datos/backup/news/news.tar.bz2 -C /var/www/news news` is giving `"tar: Cann't stat: No such file or directory"` error.

How can I solve this problem?

As it had been [answered](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59762/how-do-i-extract-a-tarball-skipping-some-of-the-leading-directories/59766#59766) in my previous question I am using `-C` option in order to skip leading directories. It was working in one Ubuntu server and now in my Ubuntu Desktop it is giving that error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using -C that means you are changing directory there. Hence, if you want to tar a directory named news in /var/www you must use:

```
sudo tar jcf /datos/backup/news/news.tar.bz2 -C /var/www/ news
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can execute your as follows:

```
(cd /var/www/news ; tar -jcf /datos/backup/news/news.tar.bz2 news)
```

This should create the archive /datos/backup/news/news.tar.bz2 with the content news. This requires, that the folder **/var/www/news/news** exists. If you intended to compress the folter /var/www/news only, use instead:

```
sudo tar jcf -C /var/www /datos/backup/news/news.tar.bz2 news
```

or

```
(cd /var/www ; tar -jcf /datos/backup/news/news.tar.bz2 news)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a `news` directory inside `/var/www/news`?

If not you could replace the last `news` with a `.` eg.:

```
sudo tar jcf /datos/backup/news/news.tar.bz2 -C /var/www/news .
```